# Recharge source javascript after loading ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reload

This is my website ( work in progress ) -> [Link](http://edonetwork.altervista.org/)

I use this my code, written on the basis of another creator. -> [Link](http://edonetwork.altervista.org/js/jquery.ajaxloading.js)

**Ajax Code**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: href,
    cache: true,
}).done(function (data) {
  ......        
// Run scripts
    $data.filter('script').each(function(){
        var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
        scriptTag.text = $(this).html();
        document.body.appendChild(scriptTag);
    });
});
```

The code allows you to load the page via ajax, then without refreshing the page. The problem arises when the page has to load javascript, they are not considered and therefore the script in the loaded page does not work.

If I can (if it is not edited) I'll link the site where I'm working and try to click in the first written [EdoNetowork](http://edonetwork.altervista.org/), then a link to an account in the topic and you'll see that the code is ignored.

How can I fix?

I think the problem is in updating the javascript page to load. But how can I recharge sources are loaded via javascript src?

Comment: It's best to put your code right here in StackOverflow, in code tags, so we can see just the problem area without going through all of your code. Also, include the returned content from your ajax request.

Comment: Thank you, next time I will do so.

Answer (score 2):

You are using $data.filter('script') which is not returning anything, instead use [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) and in your function you are using `$(this).html()` but as script has no html inside it so it will not give you anything, instead access `attr('src')` and append it to your script tag

```
// your function
$data.filter('script').each(function(){
    var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
    scriptTag.text = $(this).html(); // use $(this).attr('src')
    // scriptTag.attr('src', $(this).attr('src')) // use it like this
    document.body.appendChild(scriptTag);
});
```

you can also load javascript in your `done` callback in ajax call usinf [jquery getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/)

```
$.ajax({
.. }).done(function () {
$.getScript( "ajax/test.js", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) { ... })
});
```